# sql query concatenation in shell script

Tags: sql, shell

I have a sql query to get the count of a table

```
select count(*) from table_name_ID;
```

the above query is working as expected but the ID in table name has to be fetched from another parameter table and execute it in shell script and output has to be mailed to the user

tried multiple ways and failed, could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(5000)

SET @Query ='BCP.EXE "SELECT * FROM '+DB_NAME()+'..Table_Name" queryout  "D:\TEST\Test.txt" -T -c'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Query
```

Comment: Looks like i still have some issue in it, will get back to you guys with the complete result

Comment: post what you get on result